# how to enter double quotes in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

when ever I try to enter double quotes into the table, it shows some db error.
I tried with stripslashes and `mysql_real_escape_string`, but it fails to enter into the table.

Controller

```
function ConfirmOrder($arr) {
    $confirmation_number = substr(number_format(time() * rand(),0,'',''),0,10); 
    $ord_no = substr(number_format(time() * rand(),0,'',''),0,2); 
    $this->load->model('users_model');
    $this->users_model->ConfirmOrder($arr,$arr['order_id'],$confirmation_number,$ord_no);
    $confirm_status = array('status' => 'true', 'message' => 'Order Confirmed Successfully');

    echo json_encode($confirm_status);
}
```

Model

```
function ConfirmOrder($arr,$order_id,$confirmation_no,$ord_no) {
    $data = array(
        'order_number'        => $ord_no.strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s")),
        'order_date'          =>  date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
        'confirmation_number' =>  $confirmation_no
    );

    $this->db->where('order_id',$order_id);
    $this->db->update('mun_order_master',$data);

    if($arr['my_picks']) {
        $pick_name =  mysql_real_escape_string($arr['pick_name']);

        $data1 = array(
            'user_id'   => $arr['user_id'],
            'order_id'  => $order_id,
            'pick_name' => $pick_name,
            'add_date'  =>  date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
        );

        $this->db->insert('mun_my_picks', $data1);
        return $this->db->insert_id();
    }

    return true;
}
```

The JSON I use

```
$json='{"function":"ConfirmOrder","parameters": "order_id": "7","user_id": "25","pick_name": "SPick","my_picks": "Y"},"token":""}';
```

Comment: what is the error you're getting?

Comment: Are you using Codeigniter? This is not the right way to insert data *(Codeigniter escapes for you)*

Comment: yes i am using codeigniter

Comment: you are `CI` framework, then no need worried about quote `"` in database, CI library automatic escapes double quote, don't use `mysql_real_escape_string` function

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/89435

Comment: please share the error you are getting

Comment: You are probably inserting with missing required columns, please explain *"it shows some db error"*

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in /var/www/html/munch/application/controllers/client.php on line 25

Comment: That's not a database error - that's a PHP error.  Please paste the `clients.php` code.

Comment: hi this is a method executed by using json. I can't test this case in client.php. when testing it leads to php error.it s the backend wrk of an iphone app

Comment: That's fine, just need to see the source code of `clients.php`...

Comment: function ConfirmOrder($arr)
{
 
$confirmation_number = substr(number_format(time() * rand(),0,'',''),0,10); 
  
$ord_no = substr(number_format(time() * rand(),0,'',''),0,2); 

  
$this->load->model('users_model');
  
  $this->users_model->ConfirmOrder($arr,$arr['order_id'],$confirmation_number,$ord_no);
}the first code is included in model

Comment: Please edit your question with the **full** paste, not a portion of it.

Comment: @BurningtheCodeigniter can u please check the code

Comment: You still did not paste the **ENTIRE** code, because I can't check line 25 on the `clients.php`...!  Copy it from the top to bottom.